# MyPy fails dataclass argument with optional list of objects type

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, python-dataclasses

I'm having trouble getting MyPy to pass my script which contains a `dataclass` `Bar` with an optional argument `foos` that holds a list of `Foo` objects and defaults to an empty list.

Stranger still, adding a method `Bar.sum_foos()` which iterates through `self.foos` raises a second MyPy error. Am I misunderstanding how to set the correct types, or is something else going on?

script.py

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Optional
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


class Foo():
    pass


@dataclass
class Bar():
    foos: Optional[list[Foo]] = field(default_factory = list)

    def sum_foos(self) -> float:
        for foo in self.foos:
            pass
        return 0.0
```

2 MyPy errors

```bash
$ mypy script.py
script.py:12: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "List[_T]", variable has type "Optional[List[Foo]]")
script.py:15: error: Item "None" of "Optional[List[Foo]]" has no attribute "__iter__" (not iterable)
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Versions

```bash
$ python --version
Python 3.8.12
$ mypy --version
mypy 0.950 (compiled: yes)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the code in your question is almost fine as-is. `Optional[X]` is equivalent to `X | None` - why do you make your list optional? This field is never None, factory means that `foos` attribute will be an empty list, if not passed to the constructor. Thus declaring as `list[Foo]` is more correct and eliminates all errors.

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Optional
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


class Foo():
    pass


@dataclass
class Bar():
    foos: list[Foo] = field(default_factory=list)

    def sum_foos(self) -> float:
        for foo in self.foos:
            pass
        return 0.0
```

Comment: This actually makes the most sense to me now and solves all issues. I was incorrectly using `Optional`. I thought it should always be used if the parameter had a default value. Updating accepted answer to this, thanks!